# Tabs and osm realization

Tags: android

I need tabs for different representation of OSM map.  (My Android skills is very low)

```
______________________
| tab1 | tab2 | tab3 |
______________________
|                    |
|        Map         |
|                    |
|____________________|
```

For example, see image above. On every tab I need different zoom, different location and different markers on map.  What is the best way to realize this task? (What Android UI elements I need for tabs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FragmentTabhost` fro your requirement. Have a look on

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

However you need to bit customize the `FragmentTabhost` to prevent your fragments from recreation.